# Почему НЕ открывается модальное по событию onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть форма модального окна. В ней есть btn  который должен открывать второе модальное окно, а первое закрывать. Я прописал это в событии onclick  но оно почему-то первое закрывает, а второе не открывает. Подскажите в чем причина?

```
<?php get_template_part('receive_individual_payment_form'); ?>
<div class="modall modall_form"  id="calk_modal" style="display: none" >
   <a class='green-button'
   onClick="getElementById('win_popup_receive_individual_payment').removeAttribute('style');
            getElementById('win_popup_receive_individual_payment').style.display = 'block !important';" >
     <span>ОТПРАВИТЬ</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

receive_individual_payment_form.php:

```
<div id="win_popup_receive_individual_payment" style="display:none;">
  <div class="overlay_popup_receive_individual_payment"></div>
  <div class="visible_popup_receive_individual_payment" id="visible_popup_receive_individual_payment">
  <form>
    <!-- different <input> -->       
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" onclick=" ... "><!-- some action -->
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **document**.getElementById

Comment: функции лучше всего писать не inline кодом, а отдельными, нормальными функциями `javascript`

Comment: @Igor, первое же окно открываются по подобному же событию...Так, что дело не в этом!

Comment: @Александр Конечно, конечно. Успехов.

Comment: @Igor, Ваш сарказм немного НЕуместен!Я сейчас перед кодом сижу и вижу ЧТО работает - так Вам  и говорю! Вам скрин сбросить - раз Вы не верите?П.С.: если бы дело было в document.getElementById, то первое модальное окно НЕ открывалось бы через onclick="getElementById..."

Comment: @Александр да, не верю. да, сбросить скрин. (можно не сбрасывать, а просто в вопрос вставить)

Comment: @Александр А лучше - создать пример с работающим первым кликом и неработающим - вторым. (кнопка "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса)

Comment: @Igor, прочитайте лучше это: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro - тогда Вы, надеюсь, поймете КАК работают события onclick! Если нет, то задавайте вопрос и обсудим!

Comment: @Александр С удовольствием почитаю, спасибо. Надеюсь, что найду там пример вызова `getElementById` без `document.` перед ним. Я так понимаю, что "скрина" не будет?

Comment: @Igor, Вы прочитайте сначала !!!<input id="b1" value="Нажми Меня" onclick="alert('Спасибо!');" type="button"/>

Comment: @Александр А-а-а-а. Я, наверное, плохо объяснил. В javascript-е нет глобальной функции `getElementById` - если только Вы ее сами не написали. Однако, у объекта `document` такой метод есть.

Comment: @Igor, событие onclick УЖЕподразумевает document!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69224/discussion-between--and-igor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В проекте нашлось еще один вызов receive_individual_payment_form.php. И там оказалась одна погрешность:

```
<div class="modall modall_form"  id="calk_modal" style="display: none" >
<?php get_template_part('receive_individual_payment_form'); ?>
   <a class='green-button'
      onClick="getElementById('win_popup_receive_individual_payment').removeAttribute('style');
     <span>ОТПРАВИТЬ</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Подключение файла-формы receive_individual_payment_form было внутри элемента calk_modal, что приводило к его невидимости по всему проекту.